# Is it possible to set NXP's crlc663 chip in emulated card mode?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I'm programming a `nfc-reader` using the `clrc663` chip from NXP and I'm interested to know if this chip can be configured to emulate cards.

As far as I can see, it is not, but it would be  great to get it confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

No, the CLRC663 is only a reader mode IC. You cannot put it in card emulation mode.